# Is it possible to restrict selected in-app-purchases to specific app versions through iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Consider an app that lists its in-app products in an in-app storefront.

If an in-app purchase is created which will only be viable (handled properly) in app versions later than v1.5/build 127, may I dissociate (i.e. make invisible) that in-app purchase from earlier versions purely within iTunes Connect?

My understanding is that adding additional in-app purchases will result in them becoming available for all existing live versions of the app, and no such association mechanics are provided by Apple.  Therefore I would have to code such a restriction into the app infrastructure and handle such forward compatibility logic myself. For example, I could add an additional field in my private product information data such as "earliestViableAppBuild" and if the app version does not meet the criterion, simply omit the product from the app-store available products request.

Comment: You posted a solution in your question... I would suggest going with that solution.  As far as I know, there is no way to only associate a specific in-app purchase with specific app versions and not have them be available in future versions without completely removing them all together.

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't 100% sure because I have yet to submit an app to the live store and could not find definitive confirmation in the documentation, but at least I can plan for it ahead of time.